# how to overwrite captured value in a regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a regex into an application's regex field intended to capture return code numbers, but I need to transform a the text matched without a substitution (replace) match.

Right now a normal regex would be:

```
RETURN=(?<code>[0-9]+)
```

Which, in Perl, `RETURN=123` yields:

```
say $+{code}; # 123
```

Now I need this string `RETURN=MAX` to yield the value `999`:

```
say $+{code}; # 999
```

But I have some constraints: I can't touch the code behind nor use a substitution pattern `s///`. It MUST be a plain (Perl 5.14-flavored) regular expression match, ie, something that will become `$input_data =~ /$my_regex/`;

Is there a way to write a regex so that a captured value `MAX` be translated into something different such as `999`?

Comment: Are you saying that the *only* thing you can change is the regular expression? It should be possible using embedded Perl code `(?{ code })` but that is an *experimental feature* that shouldn't be used in production code. Otherwise I don't see a way of capturing something that isn't in the original string

Comment: Yeah, only the matching regex part can be changed. Not the code. I'll take the embedded Perl feature `?{ code }`, if it does the trick, but don't know how to get the result I want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as pie.

Just copy $+{code} into a local variable and operate on the local instead of the system variable

```
   RETURN=(?<code>[0-9]+)

   say $+{code}; # 123

   my $code = $+{code};

   say $code;  # 123

   $code = 999;

   say $code;  # 999
```